# Rosbridge and roslibjs: Unable to load the manifest for package

Tags: ros

I'm trying the communication between javascript and Ros.

I use the example code of 
"github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/examples/simple.html "
with these changes:

```
var cmdVel = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/fromRos2Can',
    messageType : 'ackermann_msgs/AckermannDrive'    
  });
```

and

```
 var twist = new ROSLIB.Message({
    speed:1.0,
    acceleration:2.0,
    jerk:3.0,
    steering_angle:4.0,
    steering_angle_velocity:5.2
  });
```

and I receive these two error message:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1404116229.210210] [Client 2] [id: advertise:/fromRos2Can:1] advertise: Unable to load the manifest for package ackermann_msgs. Caused by: ackermann_msgs

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1404116229.213060] [Client 2] [id: publish:/fromRos2Can:2] publish: Cannot infer topic type for topic /fromRos2Can as it is not yet advertised
```

**My c++ program works with AckermannDrive.msg** and a **test with a std_msg/String works too**.

Where is my mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's [a very similar post](http://answers.ros.org/question/179209/rosbridge-and-roslibjs-unable-to-load-the-manifest-for-package/) in answers.ros.org. Since that web site is the official QA forum for ROS I'd suggest continuing over there.